# Using easy rsa, how to automate client / server creation process

Tags: bash

I use easy rsa (https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa) to build my tiny ca and its clients / servers. Since its just for learning purposes, I was thinking about doing some automatization. Normally I can create files needed by client typing:

`./easyrsa build-client-full client`

but what when I need ~ 500 different client files? `cp` its not what I want here.

I tried to write a little bash script to help myself out:

```
#!/bin/bash

clients=3
pass=randompass
capass=castrongpassword

for i in `seq 1 $clients`
do
    ./easyrsa build-client-full test$i $pass $pass $capass
done
```

But it simply 'does not work'. When I build my client files in terminal I have to give 2 client passwords and the ca password. The main problem is I dont know how on earth pass it within script - is that possible? My script gives me `Ignoring unknown command option:` as output.

Comment: add an `echo "./easyrsa build-...... $pass $pass $capass"` to debug what your actual command will look like when it is executed. Is the question how to pass in $capass (ha-ha), because normally ./easyra prompts you for that value? Good luck.

Comment: If you can do with skipping the encryption of private keys, and use the 3.x version of easyrsa you can simply add "nopass" parameter to most of those commands and automate it easily.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Update (2020-04-03)

There has been some changes to EasyRSA script since I wrote the first answer.

- EasyRSA 3.0.6 (released 2019-02-02) added `--passin` and `--passout` options which correctly pass the options to OpenSSL as described in my original answer
- EasyRSA 3.0.7 (released 2020-03-31) added the ability to supply the passwords through the `EASYRSA_PASSIN` and `EASYRSA_PASSOUT` environment variables

Example:

```sh
./easyrsa --passout=file:passfile --passin=file:capassfile build-client-full $cn
```

## Original answer

Reading through the easyrsa source code, it seems that the `build-client-full` command only takes one argument: `name`. So, the error that you get is simply because it does not know what to do with the passwords you have added on the command line. I guess that the program asks you for these passwords interactively, so you *must* supply them to the program via `stdin`.

#### Hacking `easyrsa`

NOTE: OpenSSL (the backend of `easyrsa`) does not listen to `stdin` by
default. To make it do so, we must add `"-passout stdin"` (since it is a
password saved in an output file) to the OpenSSL command line. Alternatively, one could add `"-passout file:passfile"` if the passwords are kept in the file `passfile`. To make it harder, `easyrsa` does not have an easy way of adding arguments to the OpenSSL command. Thus, we must change the source code somehow. However, this is easy.

To be able to use the alternatives below, add this into the `gen_req`
function of `easyrsa` after the definition of `local opts=`:

```sh
gen_req() {
    ....
    local opts=
    opts="-passout stdin" # ADD THIS LINE
    # Alternatively: opts="-passout file:passfile"
    ....
}
```

Also, it seems that OpenSSL closes the `stdin` stream after its first
use (in `gen_req`), so it can't also be used for signing with the CA
certificate (in `sign_req`). We can tell OpenSSL to read from a file instead of
reading from `stdin` (it may also be used for the above)

```sh
sign_req() {
    local crt_type="$1" opts=
    opts="-passin file:capassfile" # ADD THIS LINE (also: create capassfile)
    ...
}
```

---

*(NOTE: The solutions below are kept mostly for future reference, in cases where multiple calls to OpenSSL is not involved...)*

#### "General solution" #1: Pipes

One way to pass passwords through stdin is to start a subshell and then pipe it to easyrsa, which would simulate the actual keypresses you would have done manually. Your example would then look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

clients=3
pass=randompass
#capass=castrongpassword   # (create the file 'capassfile' instead)

for i in `seq 1 $clients`
do
    (echo $pass; echo $pass) | ./easyrsa build-client-full test$i
done
```

Instead of creating a subshell, you could change the `(echo $pass; echo ...)` to

```sh
printf '%s\n' $pass $pass | ./easyrsa build-client-full test$i
```

or

```sh
echo -e "$pass\n$pass" | ./easyrsa build-client-full test$i
```

depending on what you find the most readable.

#### "General solution" #2: stdin redirection

The above alternative has the drawback that the passwords will appear in process listings (such as `ps`), and is thus from a security standpoint a *bad idea* if you are on a shared box. A better way would to create a file with the passwords, like this:

```
randompass
randompass
```

Then, you invoke easyrsa in your loop above by simply writing:

```sh
...
for i in `seq 1 $clients`
do
    ./easyrsa build-client-full test$i <passfile
done
```

where `passfile` is your file with the passwords. This of course assumes that you have the same password for all files.

Comment: Hmm, tried all of your examples, but any of them worked for me. When `easyrsa` prompt me about passwords, (`Enter PEM pass phrase:`) it simply 'does not see' my passwords given in a script, it seems that I need to wait for easyrsa and only when it asks me about giving passwords, I can pass them only then. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: I investigated it further, and it seems that OpenSSL is the culprit. You will have to modify the `easyrsa` program slightly to make it tell OpenSSL to actually listen to `stdin`. I added a note on how to do this.

Comment: Very interesting (and frustrating though) but I tried to do everything you wrote (changed `easyrsa` code) but the `easyrsa` still hangs out and waits for me to pass passwords in stdout - it 'doesnt see' that it should take passwords from the file instead fo stdin. Im kind a out of ideas now .. Seems you tried everything (and Im very thankful for that) but there should be some solution here, right?

Comment: Does it still ask for the PEM password or does it ask for the CA-password? Because when I do it it at least accepts the PEM passwords just fine, but I just noticed that the CA password is needed in another function. (adding `opts="-passin stdin"` to `sign_req()` might fix that.)

Comment: I updated once more, the solution provided in "Hacking `easyrsa`" works for me using the git version of `easyrsa`. The easiest solution would be to have two password files, but I kept the original answer in case something similar (which does not include OpenSSL) comes along. Hopefully this is my last edit, and at least I have learned that OpenSSL is quite picky when it comes to shell scripting :/

Comment: Can you update your answer to the new esay-rsa script ?

Comment: @executable I updated the answer to reflect the new features introduced in EasyRSA 3.0.6 and 3.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

With a few steps and with openssl 1.1.1h& easyrsa3, I tried a similar solution which allows option `-passin stdin` and/or `-passout file:passfile`

1. hardcode the option at function sign_req() line #834 in file `easy-rsa/easyrsa3/easyrsa`. change `opts=""` to  `opts="-passin stdin"`
2. use this function to create cert a single client,

   ```
   #function gen_full_client

   gen_full_client() { 
        CN=$1
        OVERWRITE=$2

    #Generate client using cn and sign it
    if [ -f "$EASYRSA_DIR/pki/private/$CN.key" ]; then         
        cat <<-EOF  | sudo $EASYRSA gen-req $CN nopass         
        $OVERWRITE
        $CN   
        EOF
    else
        cat <<-EOF  | sudo $EASYRSA gen-req $CN nopass         
        $CN   
        EOF
    fi

    #give it some time
    sleep 2
    CA_PASSWORD=$3
    #Generate client using cn and sign it
    if [ -f "$EASYRSA_DIR/pki/private/$CN.key" ]; then    
        #cat    <<-EOF | sudo $EASYRSA opts="-passout stdin" build-client-full $CN      
        cat <<-EOF   | sudo $EASYRSA sign-req client $CN 
        yes
        $(echo $CA_PASSWORD)
        EOF
    fi

    }
   ```

a simple call would create a single client entry

```
gen_full_client $1 $2 "$3"
```

iterate it over your for loop with passwords and pass it to the function and voila! It's done.

```
for i in `seq 1 $clients`
do
    gen_full_client test$i $pass $pass $capass
done
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! As an improvement I'd suggest prompting for `$CA_PASSWORD` with `read` instead of supplying it as an argument and thus leaving it in your shell history.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier in answers was options to hack EasyRsa.
But it's don't working in new versions because different code.
I found this way (tested in EasyRsa 3.1.0):

Open `/usr/share/easy-rsa/easyrsa` and find lines:

```
                        # Sanitize vars
                        if grep -Eq 'EASYRSA_PASSIN|EASYRSA_PASSOUT' "$vars"; then
                                die "\
Variable EASYRSA_PASSIN or EASYRSA_PASSOUT has been found in the configuration
file. Storing sensitive information in the configuration file is not
recommended - please remove it from there before continuing."
                        fi
```

and comment their.

Then put `set_var EASYRSA_PASSIN "pass:passphrase"` in vars file.

(where passphrase - change to your passphrase)